# php substr returning incorrect characters on a string variable from a preg_match function

Tags: php

This is sort of a rookie question, but...

I'm calling a function in another php file that uses preg_match to get a string. I then want to use substr to get a specific part of that string, however it doesn't output any of the characters in the string. When I replace the variable from the `preg_match` function, I get the right output.

Here is the basic code:

```
$title = $stream["song1"]; // From a preg_match in an external php file
echo $title; // Correctly prints the song name, in this case "mySong"
echo substr($title, 0, 1);  // Outputs a "<" symbol (why??)
```

If I run the same three lines above, but hard code the song title:

```
$title = "mySong";
echo $title; // Correctly prints the song name, in this case "mySong"
echo substr($title, 0, 1);  // Outputs a "m" symbol (correct)
```

Also, when I check the type of variable `$title` is, it returns "string".  I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid... can anyone help?

Comment: Try to check encoding of $stream["song1"]. Maybe it contains multibyte string and you need to use mb_substr. Try strlen($stream["song1"]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `$title` contains html tags, thus the first character will be the `<`.

Use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to echo the full output and then you should be able to see which part of the string you're actually looking for.

```
echo htmlentities($title);
```

---

Alternatively, you can simply remove all html tags from the string using [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$title = strip_tags($title);
echo substr($title, 0, 1); // should work
```